# How to fill the color inside the curve?

Tags: processing

I want to create a picture that has some closed areas using function `curve(...)`, but I do not know how to fill the color inside.

Is there any way to fill inside the head and body?

```
void setup(){
  size(800,800);
}

void draw(){
  background(170,243,255);
  fish();
}

void fish(){
  translate(width/2, height/2);//mouseX, mouseY

  //eye
  fill(231,255,188);
  stroke(0);
  ellipse(-100,-100,50,45);
  fill(0);
  ellipse(-100,-100,30,28);

  //head
  noFill();
  strokeWeight(2);
  stroke(157,88,255);
  curve(-400,-100,-200,-200,50,-150,150,50);
  curve(-100,-400,-200,-200,-150,50,0,100);
  curve(-300,50,-150,50,50,-150,50,-300);

  //body
  curve(-200,-350,50,-150,250,250,600,300);
  curve(-200,-200,-150,50,250,250,500,250);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [curveVertex()](https://www.processing.org/reference/curveVertex_.html) function.

This doesn't do exactly what you want, but you can play around with it until it does:

```
  //body
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  beginShape();
  curveVertex(-200, -350);
  curveVertex(50, -150);
  curveVertex(250, 250);
  curveVertex(-150, 50);
  curveVertex(-200, -200);
  endShape();
```

Note that you can have multiple blocks like this to fill in different pieces with the same color.

Comment: Oh, that function works! Thank you very much, and I still need to figure out how this can curve correctly^_^